# How to warm up django web service before opening to public?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm running django web application on AWS ecs.

I'd like to warm up the server (hit the first request and it takes some time for django to load up) when deploying a new version.

Is there a way for warming up the server before registering it to the Application load balancer?

- Edit

I'm using nginx + uwsgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed health check from nginx based ones to uwsgi related ones,

create an endpoint in django, and let the ELB use that as health check

Answer (score 1):

I asumed that you use `mod_wsgi` , because that is the behavior described [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.wiki):

> ```
> Q: Why do requests against my application seem to take forever, but then after a bit they all run much quicker?
>
> A: This is because mod_wsgi by default performs lazy loading of any application. That is, an application is only loaded the first time
> ```
>
> that a request arrives which targets that WSGI application. This means
>   that those initial requests will incur the overhead of loading all the
>   application code and performing any startup initialisation.
>
> ```
> This startup overhead can appear to be quite significant, especially if using Apache prefork MPM and embedded mode. This is
> ```
>
> because the startup cost is incurred for each process and with prefork
>   MPM there are typically a lot more processes that if using worker MPM
>   or mod_wsgi daemon mode. Thus, as many requests as there are processes
>   will run slowly and everything will only run full speed once code has
>   all been loaded.
>
> ```
> Note that if recycling of Apache child processes or mod_wsgi daemon processes after a set number of requests is enabled, or for
> ```
>
> embedded mode Apache decides itself to reap any of the child
>   processes, then you can periodically see these delayed requests
>   occurring.
>
> ```
> Some number of the benchmarks for mod_wsgi which have been posted do not take into mind these start up costs and wrongly try to compare
> ```
>
> the results to other systems such as fastcgi or proxy based systems
>   where the application code would be preloaded by default. As a result
>   mod_wsgi is painted in a worse light than is reality. If mod_wsgi is
>   configured correctly the results would be better than is shown by
>   those benchmarks.
>
> ```
> For some cases, such as when WSGIScriptAlias is being used, it is actually possible to preload the application code when the processes
> ```
>
> first starts, rather than when the first request arrives. To preload
>   an application see the WSGIImportScript directive.

I think you may try to use `WSGIScriptAlias` see more [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationDirectives.wiki#WSGIImportScript)

Comment: I'm using nginx + uwsgi, mod_wsgi is apache I guess?

Comment: in nginx there is a `--lazy-apps` option replacement of `fork` , maybe that help here